# Stuck in the proof of the Fubini Theorem for integrable functions

Tags: proof-explanation, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I'm stuck in an assumption that my book makes directly, and which is possibly direct, but I'm not seeing it... I put the question in context: I'm proving Fubini's Theorem for Lebesgue-integrable functions, and I have already proove it for non-negative measurable functions. My formulation (with my notation) of the theorem, is: ''If $f:\mathbb{R}^{p}=\mathbb{R}^{k}\times\mathbb{R}^{n}\to \mathbb{R}$ is integrable, then, for almost all $y\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, the function (called ''section'') $f_{y}: \mathbb{R}^{k}\to \mathbb{R}$ (defined as $f_{y}(x)=f(x,y)$) is integrable, and, because of that the function $y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\to \int_{\mathbb{R}^{k}}f(x,y)dx\in \mathbb{R}$ is well-defined in almost every point of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Moreover, that last function is integrable in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and the following equality holds: $\int\int_{\mathbb{R}^{k}\times\mathbb{R}^{n}}f(x,y)dxdy=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^{k}}f(x,y)dx\right)dy$''.
For proving it, I have easily stated the integrability of $f_{y}$ (due to the fact that $f=f^{+}-f^{-}$, and for being $f^{+}=\max\{0,f\}$ and $f^{-}=-\min\{0,f\}$ non-negative measurable functions (where I can apply the Fubini Theorem for this functions that I have already proven). But, when I have to proove the integrativity of the function $y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\to \int_{\mathbb{R}^{k}}f(x,y)dx$, the book simply states me that this is easily seen directly from the fact that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{k}} f_{y}(x)dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{k}} (f^{+})_{y}(x)dx-\int_{\mathbb{R}^{k}} (f^{-})_{y}(x)dx\in\mathbb{R}$... I'm not seeing this.

I have tried to go this way: show that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}$$\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}^{k}}f(x,y)dx\right|dy<\infty$, in order to show that the function above is integrable. From them, with the descomposition in $f_{y}=(f^{+})_{y}-(f^{-})_{y}$, I have tried to proove the statement but I'm lost... Is just probably that I'm stupidly stuck... but, If someone could give me some advice or help, I will be very grateful. Thanks is advanced!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $g(y) = \int f(x,y)\,dx$.  By the triangle inequality for integrals, $|g(y)| \le \int |f(x,y)|\,dx$.  So by monotonicity of the integral, $\int |g(y)|\,dy \le \int \int |f(x,y)| \,dx\,dy$ which is finite because $f$ is assumed to be integrable.

Comment: But being integrable means that $\int\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}\times\mathbb{R}^{k}}|f(x,y)|dxdy$ is finite... not that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}(\int_{\mathbb{R}^{k}}|f(x,y)|dx)dy$ is finite, no? that is just what I'd like to show... sorry for the disturbance, I'm getting quite confused...

Comment: @rubikman23: You said you already proved the non-negative version of Fubini's theorem.  $|f|$ is a non-negative measurable function, so that version tells you exactly that $\int\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}\times\mathbb{R}^{k}}|f(x,y)|dxdy$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}(\int_{\mathbb{R}^{k}}|f(x,y)|dx)dy$ are equal.

Comment: So true... I'm seing it now... Thank you so much for everything!